# Optimising a merge based on two columns in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'message' : (["hi","hi","hello?","bye","are you there?","how are you?"]),
                     'serial' : ([14,12,13,13,14,14]),
                     'messageOrder': (1,1,1,2,3,2)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'message' : (["hi","hi","hello?","bye","are you there?","how are you?"]),
                    'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'D' : np.array([3] * 6,dtype='int32'),
                    'serial' : ([14,12,13,13,14,14])})
```

I am looking for the best way to merge the messageOrder column from df1 to df2 (df2 has many more columns I didn't include in the example). I thought of iterating through all the rows and:

- Verify the "serial" is identical between two rows in df1 and df2
- Match the "message" columns according to its content.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

the dataframes are 14,000 rows long, each "serial" has 1-20 values.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2)` ?

Comment: The order of the rows is not the same between df1 and df2,
I can't tell based only on the "serial" what is the "messageOrder" without comparing the content, and in many occurences the content is the same in different "serial" columns :)

Comment: Order of rows doesn't matter.. `pandas.merge` by default [merges on common columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Interesting, when I try
    df1.merge(df2)
only a tiny fraction of the table stays (400 out of 14000), when I try 
    df1.merge(df2, on = 'serial')
the number of rows become 37105.
How can I get around this?